# using angular terms to match the code symantics

Tags: angularjs

Consider my code below, which I don't understand fully as I have been doing a lot of "monkey see monkey do" while looking at other people codes.

Please correct my line of thought, here we go;

1. In app.js, when the compiler sees this

   ```
    angular
    .module('angApp', ['ngRoute', 'MainMenuCtrl'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', routeProvider]);
   ```

   It defines a module and since its identifier is the same as what's declared in the html tag ng-app attributes, this is the 'main' module. if this is correct, I could call it mainMod instead of angApp to cary its real meaning.
2. In controllers.js, when the compiler sees this

   ```
   var myApp = angular.module('MainMenuCtrl', ['ngAnimate']);
   myApp.controller('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', MainMenuCtrl]);
   ```

   The first line defines a new module (previously declared as dependency for angApp in step 1), named MainMenuCtrl. If this is correct, I could cal it mainMenuMod instead of MainMenuCtrl.

   The second line injects a controller called MainMenuCtrl, this name is mentioned two times in this line, the first mention is a reference to the module that was just defined in the first line, the second mention is the name of the constructor function. If that is correct, I could change the first MainMenuCtrl to MainMenuMod.  So the new names better describe the semantics.

   ```
    angular
     .module('mainMod', ['ngRoute', 'MainMenuMod'])
     .config(['$routeProvider', routeProvider]);

     var whatever = angular.module('MainMenuMod', ['ngAnimate']);
     whatever.controller('MainMenuMod', ['$scope', '$http', MainMenuCtrl]);
   ```

Am I in the right or wrong? thanks

```js
//---app.js-------------------
(function () {
     'use strict';

     angular
         .module('angApp', ['ngRoute', 'MainMenuCtrl'])
         .config(['$routeProvider', routeProvider]);
 })();

 function routeProvider ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.when('/menuItems', {
         url: "/menuItems",
         templateUrl: 'views/mainMenu.html',
         controller: 'MainMenuCtrl'
     }).when('/first_page', {
         url: "/first_page",
         templateUrl: 'views/first_page.html',
         controller: 'FirstPageController'
     }).when('/second_page', {
         url: "/second_page",
         templateUrl: 'views/second_page.html',
         controller: 'SecondPageController'
     })
     .otherwise({      //home page
         redirectTo: '/menuItems'
     });
 }

//---controllers.js-------------------
var myApp = angular.module('MainMenuCtrl', ['ngAnimate']);
myApp.controller('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', MainMenuCtrl]);

function MainMenuCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('js/mainMenu.json').then(
        function (response) {
            $scope.menuItems = response.data;
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("http error");
        }
    )
```

```html
//---index.html--------------
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <base href="http://localhost:63342/project_student/">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/headerCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/first_page.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/second_page.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The names for modules and for everything else don't interfere, so having `MainMenuCtrl` controller and `mainMenuCtrl` module (modules usually follow pascalCase naming convention, separated with dots for namespacing) is ok and unambiguous. Appending module name with 'Mod' or 'Module' suffix is redundant.

It is semantically correct to have `mainMenu` module that loads `mainMenuCtrl` module if there is a possibility that they will be tested apart.